# Why is there a である between a noun and というところだ?

Tags: grammar

> 「う、うむ！よろしくだ、シドーではない女！」 「……は、はい、よろしくお願いします」
> 頰に汗を垂らしながら握手を交わす。三人娘は少しだけ訝しげな顔をしたものの、まあいつもの十香**である**というところで納得したのだろう、深く追及はしてこなかった。

The protagonist 士道/シドー, a boy, was dressed as a girl. His classmate 十香 easily recognized him but 士道 asked 十香 to pretend not to know him because he did not want the three girls to know he is 士道. 十香 happily did as she was told by saying「う、うむ！よろしくだ、シドーではない女！」.

Could you please explain why there is a である before というところで?

https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=11855

According to the above link, when connecting a noun with というところだ, we don’t put anything in between. So we should just say 十香というところで, it seems.

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: I added a 'not' in the edit because it didn't make logical sense to me without it. Please check that I haven't inadvertently changed what you meant to say.

Comment: @user3856370 Oh. Thank you for editing it. It should be “he did not want ...”.

Comment: The site you linked describes the というところ that attaches to 「程度や数量を表す単語」. This is different. I think if you break your sentence down to its parts: である、という、and ところ, it would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

> まあいつもの十香であるというところで納得したのだろう、深く追及はしてこなかった。

The meaning of this sentence is: "They didn't pursue the matter further, prescribing the odd comment (「う、うむ！よろしくだ、シドーではない女！」) to 十香's usual weirdness".

ところで describes "where" (in the abstract sense) the 納得 happened (similar to 落とし所). である means "to be", and here it comments that the behavior of 十香 is how she is (usually).

So all combined, it says the three girls formed a mental comment that the odd behavior fits with 十香's character (いつもの十香である), and goes on to say they 納得ed at this thought.

Comment: Thank you very much. So this ところ just means "place"? It's not used figuratively (for example, 範囲, 程度, etc)? https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D/

Comment: It is used figuratively (it refers to the narrow mental state that contains the reason for 納得) @chinoalpha

Comment: Thanks again. Could you refer me to a dictionary entry for the ところ in this sense? The closest definition of this ところ I could find is ㋒部分。箇所。点。「悪い―を直す」「粋な―のある人だ」. But I'm not sure.

Comment: I'd say ㋓場面。局面 or ㋕事柄。内容 is the closest. Another example could be「給与に不満はあったが、家具づくりを学べるというところで契約を決断した」